# Вывод .tif файлов после выбора папки из QComboBox

Tags: c++, qt

Необходимо при выборе папки из `QComboBox`, показать файлы `.tif` из данной папки в `listView`. 
При запуске программы, загружаю доступные папки в указанной директории.

```
QDir path("/home/dev/test-project/");
QStringList files = path.entryList(QDir::Dirs);
ui->cB_Karte->addItems(files);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
На данном скриншоте видны все файлы и папки, нужны только `.tif` файлы без их расшерения.

Какой ивент нужно указать `QComboBox`, чтобы при выборе он показывал файлы `.tif` в `listView`?

При нажатии на файл в `listView` - как выполнить другую функцию?

Использовать можно и не `ListView`.

В данный момент сделал следующие:

```
void MainWindow::on_cB_Karte_currentIndexChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
    //TODO currentPath editieren
    ui->treeView->clear();
    folderPath = QDir::currentPath();
    folderDir = QDir(folderPath);

    QFileInfoList pngList = folderDir.entryInfoList(QStringList("*.tif"), QDir::Files | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);
    for(const auto &item : pngList){
        ui->treeView->addItem(item.fileName());
    }
}
```

При выполнении кода выше, не добавляется новый файл с выбраной папки.

Comment: как-то так: `path.setNameFilters({"*.tiff"})`, нет?

Comment: @Fat-Zer проблема в том, что не знаю как загрузить файлы в listView и как потом выполнить функцию по выбору

Comment: @Fat-Zer обновил вопрос, вчера кое-что набросал, но не работает.

Comment: и при чём тут выбранная папка, когда ты добавляешь всё с `QDir::currentPath()`?

Comment: @Fat-Zer уже решил. Не пойму только одного, файл лежит к примеру в `./map/1.tiff` но показывает через `QFileInfo str = currentText;` `qDebug() << str.absoluteFilePath();` `./1.tiff`

Comment: хз... УМВР `echo -e '#include <QDebug>\n #include <QFileInfo>\n int main(void) { QFileInfo fp ("./dir/1.tiff"); qDebug() << fp.absoluteFilePath(); return 0; }' >/tmp/qt-qfp.cpp && g++ -fPIC /tmp/qt-qfp.cpp -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -lQt5Core -o /tmp/a.out && /tmp/a.out` => /home/alexander/dir/1.tiff

Comment: @Fat-Zer как с помощью `QDir::currentPath();` указать, что искать не в этой же папке а на уровень ниже? Т.е `/opt/test/bin` в `/opt/test/share/`

Comment: QDir::cdUp(), например... пора учиться заглядывать в документацию...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще всего использовать QFileSystemModel.

```
class Widget: public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
    QComboBox *cb;
    QListView *list;
    QFileInfoList paths;
    QFileSystemModel *fs;
public:
    explicit Widget (QWidget *parent);
public slots:
    void changeModelIndex(int index);
    // ...
};

// ...

Widget::Widget (QWidget *parent): QWidget(parent) {
    // ...
    cb = new QComboBox (this);
    QDir path("/home/dev/test-project/");
    paths = path.entryInfoList(QDir::Dirs);

    cb = new QComboBox (this);
    for (const auto& fi:paths) {
        cb->addItem (fi.fileName());
    }
    connect (cb, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), this, SLOT(changeModelIndex(int));

    fs = new QFileSystemModel (this);
    fs->setNameFilters({"*.tiff"});
    fs->setFilters(QDir::Files);
    list = new QListView (this);
    list->setModel (fs);
    // ...
}

void Widget::changeModelIndex(int index) {
    fs->setRootDirectory (paths[index]);
}
```

Пример собран наспех и может содержать ошибки, но показаны все основные моменты.